# Merging list with another list python without loops

Tags: string, python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I have 2 pandas series that look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
listA = [5,4,3]
listB = ["a","b","c"]
s = pd.Series(listA)
print(s)
p = pd.Series(listB)
print(p)
```

And I would like to obtain a list of the 2 lists mixed together as strings like this:

```
listTogether = ["a5","a4","a3","b5","b4","b3","c5","c4","c3"]
t = pd.Series(listTogether)
print(t)
```

Do you have any hint? Is it possible to do by avoiding loops?

Thanks so much in advance for the help

Comment: What have you tried? This could be achieved with `zip` and a comprehension/`map`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trick from `MultiIndex`

```
listTogether = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([p,s.astype(str)]).map(''.join).tolist()
listTogether 
Out[242]: ['a5', 'a4', 'a3', 'b5', 'b4', 'b3', 'c5', 'c4', 'c3']
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I have always been struggling on how to use MultiIndex. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are looping whether you like it or not.

```
[f'{b}{a}' for b in listB for a in listA]

['a5', 'a4', 'a3', 'b5', 'b4', 'b3', 'c5', 'c4', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools product

```
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(list(product(p.tolist(),s.astype(str).tolist()))).apply(''.join, axis = 1).tolist()

839 µs ± 18.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

['a5', 'a4', 'a3', 'b5', 'b4', 'b3', 'c5', 'c4', 'c3']
```

If you want a very efficient solution, go pure python way

```
[''.join(i) for i in list(product(p.tolist(),s.astype(str).tolist()))]
79 µs ± 924 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `zip` may help you.

You can do something like that for your lists, however it involves a for loop  :

```
listTogether = ['{}{}'.format(a,b) for (a,b) in zip(listA,listB)]
```